# Personal malloc function that uses a data structure to handle memory

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, malloc, allocation

I have this function that will take in a number of bytes to allocate and send back only if it is available and the size of the requested number of bytes fit into my small managed memory.
My question:

The appropriate data structure is not being allocated for and I'm afraid I will not get back correct addresses. Does anyone know how I can test this function using it as a library in another program?

**THE DATA STRUCTURE**

```
typedef struct memBlock{
struct memBlock* next;
unsigned long size;  // Size of this block
unsigned int is_used;  // bool 0 = not used 1 = used
} memBlock;
```

**THE MALLOC FUNCTION:**

```
char *mm_alloc(unsigned long no_of_chars){

if (!has_initialized) {
    printf("No Memory has been intialized, PLEASE INITIALIZE THE MEMORY BEFORE calling This function\n");
    exit(1);
}


void *cur_location; // this is where we are currentl in our memory pool

memBlock *current_loc_mb; // the current mem block location

char *mem_location; // mem location we will return to the user

/* We are going to have to include the size of our data struct when we are searching for open memory*/
no_of_chars = no_of_chars + sizeof(struct memBlock);

mem_location = 0; // set to 0 until a proper size has been found

cur_location = managed_memory_start; // start at the beginning of our allocated memory

// go until there is no more memory left, allocate until we get to the end of our managed memory
while (managed_memory_start != NULL) {

    /*cur_location and cur_loc_mcb are at the same address initially,
but we use the current location as a pointer to move around our managed memory*/

    cur_loc_mcb = (memBlock *)cur_location; 

    // if our current location is not used
        if (!cur_loc_mcb->is_used) {

            if (cur_loc_mcb->size >= no_of_chars) {

                // we have found a size big enough or equal to what the user asks for
                cur_loc_mcb->is_used = 1; 
                mem_location = cur_location; 

                break;

            }
        }

// at this point we dont have a size big enough, move to the next one
cur_location = cur_location + cur_loc_mcb->size; 

}
/*Move the memory past or MCB and return*/

mem_location = mem_location + sizeof(struct memBlock);

return mem_location;
}
```

Comment: "Does anyone know how i can test this function using it as a library in another program?"  This would imply that you have a test suite for another program, as well.  Otherwise, how do you know that you're getting good coverage of *their* functionality, and therefore *your* functionality?  A better thing to do might be to automated tests for your own malloc library, because then you can guarantee coverage of corner cases.  If you already have this, then what you asked about in this question might be a good second step.

Comment: Are you compiling as `C`? The cast (`cur_loc_mcb = (memBlock *)cur_location;`) is spurious and should be left for the compiler to do.

Comment: @ Merlyn Morgan-Graham,  i am looking for some test case ideas to these functionalities that i am currently writing.

Comment: There's no way to tell if you ask for more memory than available in the largest block. If you do, you'll never leave the while loop (until the program segfaults, that is)

Comment: so the while(mem_start !=null) will run forever, even if i carefully go through my entire block. how else can i go through my chunk of memory until i have none of it left

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you set mem_location

```
            mem_location = cur_location;
```

and later, just before returning its value, you change it

```
    mem_location = mem_location + sizeof(struct memBlock);
```

it doesn't seem right ...

Comment: It looks like he has the allocation metadata inline with the usable memory, directly preceding each of the allocated blocks and free blocks. He steps through the metadata entries with `cur_location = cur_location + cur_loc_mcb->size;` till he finds a free space big enough. Then he just steps past the metadata to get a pointer to the free space the programmer can write to. But yeah, no reason to change it twice.

Comment: i am doing exactly what Null Set is talking about. The mem_location = mem_location is just to align it back before i send the user back the allocated space